# Select one before last in MySql custom function

Tags: mysql, limit

I want a function that given a N returns the N-1th Product name from the `Products` table sorted by the `Sales` column

The `Products` Table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Products(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Sales int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

My current function definition:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION getName(X INT) RETURNS varchar(255)
BEGIN
  RETURN (
      SELECT 
        Name
      FROM Products
      ORDER BY Sales
      LIMIT 1 OFFSET X - 1
  );
END
```

But it is giving me a syntax error around `X - 1`. How can I use the minus operator with a custom function argument. For my use case I need to do the negation inside the function rather than outside. (running mysql 5.7).

**tldr:**

Why does `OFFSET X - 1` throw a syntax error and what is the alternative?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - and why do you want a function, specifically?

Comment: @Strawberry What? I have included the schema, what more do you want? All I ask is why cannot I use `X-1` in offset? The function is a required spec from my team so I have little control over what it is. They need this `-1` to deal with zero indexing. Obviously it would be easier to deal with up the chain but surely it is possible to do this simple operation?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you have to use a static number after LIMIT. You can construct a string of SQL and then execute the string-SQL. See EXECUTE statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html says:

> Within stored programs, `LIMIT` parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.

In other words, LIMIT and OFFSET don't accept expressions like `X - 1`.

You can do this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getName(X INT) RETURNS varchar(255)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
  DECLARE local_offset INT;
  SET local_offset = X - 1;
  RETURN (
      SELECT
        Name
      FROM Products
      ORDER BY Sales
      LIMIT 1 OFFSET local_offset
  );
END
```